# Mongo: Fetching documents that aren't referenced in another collection

Tags: mongodb

Lets assume that I have two collections in my Mongo database: `A` & `B`.  Each `A` document may have reference to `B`, but `B` documents don't have references back to `A`.

How can I efficiently find all documents in `B` that **are not** referenced by a document in `A`?

Is there a more effective approach than retrieving all documents in `B` and manually comparing against `A` documents?  Can this be done with map reduce?

Should I consider adding references from `B` to `A` to support the query?  Since Mongo doesn't support transactions, I had avoided any two way references to avoid any chance of an inconsistent state in the event of a failure.

Also, I need to be able to effectively page through these results, if that impacts the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo-code:

```
// Get the set of B document ids that are referenced by A documents.
var bref_ids = db.A.distinct('b_id');

// Get the set of all other B documents.
var unreferenced_b_docs = db.B.find({_id: {$nin: bref_ids}});
```

Comment: Thanks, Johnny.  I was hoping there was a more efficient way, but I'm starting to think that I should just add references from `B` back to `A`.  The query would then be simple, but I'd need to add some logic to handle resolution of any inconsistencies in the database that result from some fault while updating.

Comment: I'd avoid the back-reference if at all possible.  Too much opportunity for inconsistency.  If you add an index to your `b_id` property in the `A` collection the performance should be decent.  Obviously it depends on the specifics of your situation though.

Comment: Warning - this won't scale. The `distinct` operation is limited to 16mb max data size.

Comment: @EladNava Yep, there is a limit, but 16MB holds over a million 12-byte object ids.